# Flutter VSCode and Nox Emulator wont Connect

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

i tried all the solutions to connect VScode project with Nox player. But,when i run flutter doctor it still end's up showing "No Devices Connected"

Steps i Followed:
1.opened up nox emulator and VSCode project
2.Cmd and ran the "netstat -aon | findstr PID" (without quotes)
3.adb connect TCP (tried connecting to all TCP onebyone but no luck)
4.ran flutter doctor but i still shows the same.

also upgraded the flutter pub, and Android Studio AVD are too Heavy to operate.

PLEASE Help me with this.

Comment: rename nox_adb.exe, restart nox player then adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001, check with flutter devices

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Task Manager
2. Navigate to tab Details
3. Find NoxVMHandle.exe
4. Remember the PID Number, for example 12340
5. Open command prompt
6. Klik netstat -aon | findstr 12340
7. Then pick port that bind and listening for localhost then connect to nox player wtih adb command, for example -> adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
8. Just wait for few second until and after connected
9. Open VS Code then see the bottom right status for the devices listed
10. Try run command flutter doctor to make sure that connected with flutter

Comment: adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001 WORKS! Thanks.